# Weird questions about Probability: how to understand mortality rate and admission rate

Tags: probability

These were very intuitive questions about probability. I did not give too much thought to them.
However, my younger siblings asked me "why", and then I became confused. I came up with my own explanations. Please tell me whether my explanations are correct or not, and share with me your explanations so that I can teach my siblings and myself.

---

Question 1:

> Assume the mortality rate of a disease is 35%, which means that 35 out of 100 patients die. Then mathematically speaking, without considering other conditions, if somebody gets this disease, can we say the probability of him dying is 35%? Why can we think this way?

My explanation:

> When we encounter this type of problem, we imagine we randomly think of ourselves as one of the 100 patients, 35 of which are going to die. Therefore, it is just like the chance of picking a red ball out of a box containing 65 white balls and 35 red balls.

---

Question 2:

> Assume the school accepts 7 applicants per 100 applicants. Then mathematically speaking, without considering other conditions, if somebody applies for this school, can we say the probability of him getting accepted is 7%? Why can we think this way?

My explanation:

> When we encounter this type of problem, we imagine we randomly think of ourselves as one of the 100 applicants, 7 of which are going to be accepted. Therefore, it is just like the chance of picking a red ball out of a box containing 93 white balls and 7 red balls.

---

Comment: The balls thing is kind of reductive, because the two questions do not take into account how controllable the situations are, so it is not very pedagogical. Make sure the young siblings fully get the fundamental 'blindness' we we apply these rates to real situations.

Comment: @Snoop If we only talk about the probability without taking other conditions into account, are my explanations workable? I don't know how to explain using a simple way. For example, mortality rates of disease A and disease B are 90% and 20% respectively. One would expect the chance of dying is much higher when he gets disease A. Why can he think like that?

Comment: When we talk about the probability of a Bernoulli trial (dead vs not dead) we talk about the proportion of the dead that we would observe if we could sample infinite iid patients. Given $N$ patients (and known $p$) we would expect on average that $Np$ will die of the disease. This is why the perception of chance of mortality is higher.

Comment: Yes, I know. But how does one associate himself with the result (N as the number of patients; p as the probability; the number of patients dying is Np) when he becomes a patient of that disease. The seemingly intuitive process is hard to explain. Is there a simple way to illustrate it for younger learners? My way of seeing this is that I, as a patient, will become one of the N patients. Therefore, the probability of me picking and becoming a patient who is going to die is p.

Comment: There is a nonzero probability that none of N patients will die from the disease.. you should say on average. I find it strange that they do not get the fact that once you get the disease, you may die. Maybe they are missing another 'hidden' logical passage.